# DataGrip PostgreSQL Stored Procedure Error

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I'm constantly getting this error in DataGrip when trying to create a procedure in PostgreSQL

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
```

This is the block I'm trying to run (It works on my friend's mac)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE name_p(IN modelNumber integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
 BEGIN
 DELETE FROM product WHERE model = modelNumber;
 DELETE FROM pc WHERE model = modelNumber;
 END;
 $$;
```

I got **Postgres 11.2 installed**, so everything should be up to date..

Comment: Please run `SELECT version()` and tell the result.

Comment: Managed to solve it, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution!**

Apparently you need to change the port in the config file for PostgreSQL. It's all described in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33182/how-do-i-set-which-postgresql-version-is-to-be-used-by-default).